# Input shape and Conv1d in Keras

Tags: python, keras

The first layer of my neural network is like this:

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=40,
                 kernel_size=25,
                 input_shape=x_train.shape[1:],
                 activation='relu',
                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-6),
                 strides=1))
```

if my input shape is `(600,10)`

i get `(None, 576, 40)`   as output shape

if my input shape is `(6000,1)`

i get `(None, 5976, 40)` as output shape

so my question is what exactly is happening here? is the first example simply ignoring 90% of the input?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not "ignoring" a 90% of the input, the problem is simply that if you perform a 1-dimensional convolution with a kernel of size *K* over an input of size *X* the result of the convolution will have size *X* - *K* + 1. If you want the output to have the same size as the input, then you need to extend or "pad" your data. There are several strategies for that, such as add zeros, replicate the value at the ends or wrap around. Keras' [`Convolution1D`](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv1d) has a `padding` parameter that you can set to `"valid"` (the default, no padding), `"same"` (add zeros at both sides of the input to obtain the same output size as the input) and `"causal"` (padding with zeros at one end only, idea taken from [WaveNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.03499)).

*Update*

About the questions in your comments. So you say your input is `(600, 10)`. That, I assume, is the size of one example, and you have a batch of examples with size `(N, 600, 10)`. From the point of view of the convolution operation, this means you have `N` examples, each of with a length of at most `600` (this "length" may be time or whatever else, it's just the dimension across which the convolution works) and, at each of these `600` points, you have vectors of size `10`. Each of these vectors is considered an atomic sample with `10` features (e.g. price, heigh, size, whatever), or, as is sometimes called in the context of convolution, "channels" (from the RGB channels used in 2D image convolution).

The point is, the convolution has a kernel size and a number of output channels, which is the `filters` parameter in Keras. In your example, what the convolution does is take every possible slice of 25 contiguous 10-vectors and produce a single 40-vector for each (that, for every example in the batch, of course). So you pass from having 10 features or channels in your input to having 40 after the convolution. It's not that it's using only one of the 10 elements in the last dimension, it's using all of them to produce the output.

If the meaning of the dimensions in your input is not what the convolution is interpreting, or if the operation it is performing is not what you were expecting, you may need to either reshape your input or use a different kind of layer.

Comment: That is not really what I'm asking. Lets say i pad with 0's then my output shapes would be `(None, 600, 40)` and `(None, 6000, 40)` respectively. What I'm wondering is what happens to the other 9 arrays in `(600,10)` in other words should the output shape be something like `(None, 576, 40, 10)` instead of just  `(None, 576, 40)`

Comment: @drulludanni I've updated the answer with more explanations.

Comment: So, we have 10 sequences of length 600 in every sample. Every sequence represents a feature. So we have e.q. 600 consecutive values of temperature, 600 consecutive values of humidity, etc in every sample. Conv1D layer looks for patterns in every sequence *separately*. Do I get it right?

Comment: @gisek Mostly, yes. Every input sample would be a sequence of 600 temp values, humidity values, etc. However, a convolution layer does not generally treat each of the features ("channels") separately, but rather will learn patterns across all of them (for example, you may go from 10 "channels" to 5 "channels", each of which is computed from combined information of the original 10). If you want to treat each channel separately, you can split the data or do a "separable convolution" (e.g. [`tf.nn.separable_conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/separable_conv2d) in TensorFlow)